# What kind of malicious activity could an RPC gateway inflict on the user?

Tags: signature, private-key, rpc, external-api, attacks

Let's say, a third-party RPC gateway for an Ethereum-like networks decided to turn itself into a malicious one.  Apart from the likes of selling users' data, what kind of malicious activity could it inflict on the user? Namely, **only in regards to the user's RPC/API requests or transactions**.

It could view user's requests in the plain text, right?

Could it replay them on user's behalf?

Could it break the integrity of requests or transactions thus modifing them? Given that they're signed with a user's private key.

What other malicious activities could it do too?

Comment: There are a lot of details being glossed over with "Let's say, a third-party RPC gateway for an Ethereum-like networks decided to turn itself into a malicious one." but here is a good list to start with: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/attack-and-defense/